# Duda para editar campos personalizados en edit-profile.php de wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Lo que pasa es que tengo una tienda woocommerce, donde yo creé una tabla nueva que se llama wp_users_points y de alguna manera ya logré que funcione para que se otorguen puntos cada que alguien hace una compra. Pero ahora intento crear nuevos campos en la sección de "Usuarios" y en todos los usuarios, yo como administrador, podré modificar los puntos de cualquiera de ellos manualmente.

Esto ya **funciona SOLAMENTE para editar mis propios puntos** (es decir, el usuario que inició sesión y que se edita a sí mismo). Cuando me edito a mi mismo, se refresca la pantalla y la información se actualiza en pantalla y en mi base de datos. Pero cuando intento cambiar la info de otro usuario, me dice en pantalla **"ID de usuario no válido"** y la información no se actualiza ni en base de datos, ni en pantalla.

Para no enredarlos más, les comparto mi código que coloqué en functions.php:

```php
     add_action('show_user_profile', 'add_custom_form_user_profile');
     add_action('edit_user_profile', 'add_custom_form_user_profile');

     function add_custom_form_user_profile( $user ) {
         global $wpdb;
         $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'users_points';
    
         // Obtener ID del usuario que se edita
         $user_id = $user->ID;
    
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['update_points'])) {
            // Obtener datos del formulario
            $points = sanitize_text_field($_POST['points']);
            $membership = sanitize_text_field($_POST['membership']);

            // Actualizar o insertar datos en la base de datos
            $existing_record = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE user_id = $user_id");

            if (!isset($existing_record)) {
                $wpdb->insert(
                    $table_name,
                    array(
                       'user_id' => $user_id,
                       'membership' => $membership,
                       'points' => $points,
                    )
                );
            } else {
                $wpdb->update(
                    $table_name,
                    array(
                       'membership' => $membership,
                       'points' => $points,
                    ),
                    array('user_id' => $user_id)
                );
            } 
        }
    
        // Retrieve record for that user
        $existing_record = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE user_id = $user_id");

        // Check if exists record in DB
        if( !isset( $existing_record) ) {
            $membership = "standard";
            $points = 0.00;
        } else {
            $membership = $existing_record -> membership;
            $points = $existing_record -> points;
        } ?>
    
        <h2>My custom form</h2>
        <form method="post">
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="current_points">Puntos actuales</label></th>
                    <td><input type="number" name="points" min="0" step=".01" value="<?php echo $points;?>"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="membership">Membresía</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <select name="membership" id="membership">
                          <option value="Standard" <?php selected( $membership, 'Standard' ); ?>>Standard</option>
                          <option value="Gold" <?php selected( $membership, 'Gold' ); ?>>Gold</option>
                          <option value="Premium" <?php selected( $membership, 'Premium' ); ?>>Premium</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="update_points" value="Actualizar puntos" />
            </p>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
```

Por aquí también vi que la mejor manera de actualizar datos es usando otro tipo de hooks (personal_options_update, edit_user_profile_update), los cuales son los siguientes, pero ni si quiera funcionaba:

```php
    add_action('personal_options_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
    add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');

    function save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id) {
        error_log("modifying edit user");
        if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
            error_log("you're not allowed to edit this user");
            return false;
        }
        
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'users_points';

        $points = sanitize_text_field($_POST['points']);
        $membership = sanitize_text_field($_POST['membership']);
        error_log("you can edit this user");
        
        // Actualizar o insertar datos en la base de datos
        $existing_record = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE user_id = $user_id");

        if (!isset($existing_record)) {
            error_log("inserting new record");
            $wpdb->insert(
                $table_name,
                array(
                   'user_id' => $user_id,
                   'membership' => $membership,
                   'points' => $points,
                )
            );
        } else {
            error_log("updating record");
            $wpdb->update(
                $table_name,
                array(
                   'membership' => $membership,
                    'points' => $points,
                ),
                array('user_id' => $user_id)
            );
        }
    }
```

Desde los error_log que coloqué, me di cuenta que no funcionaba (ni si quiera entraba a la función), ***por lo que opté por usar un formulario en mi primera función y ahí mismo usar lo de "isset($_POST['update_points'])"***. Cuando imprimo el $user_id, SI imprime correctamente el id del usuario al que quiero editar o al que estoy accediendo a sus datos, pero como les decía, al intentar guardar, me mostraba ese error de **"ID de usuario no válido"**, esto solamente para modificar registros de alguien más.

Así que, estaré muy agradecido si alguien me pudiera ayudar, ya que no he encontrado la manera de solucionar esto ni estoy entendiendo porqué ocurre este error.

---

ACTUALIZACIÓN:
Ya logré realizar esto. La solución:
En las acciones (show_user_profile y edit_user_profile) JAMÁS usen un formulario dentro y menos coloquen un input type="submit", bloquea el botón de actualizar usuario de la página "edit-user.php" y bloquea las acciones (personal_options_update, edit_user_profile_update).

Después de quitar el formulario, TAMPOCO actualicen los datos dentro de las primeras 2 acciones, vayan poco a poco debugeando en las acciones (personal_options_update, edit_user_profile_update), recibiendo sus campos con:

```
$myVariable = sanitize_text_field($_POST['my_field']);
```

Donde mi field, corresponde al atributo name de tus input.

PROBLEMA SOLUCIONADO!!!!!! Gracias a los que se tomaron su tiempo por responder y darme sugerencias de no usar functions.php. MIL GRACIAS.

Comment: Dos consejos: 1- Cambia el prefijo de la DB. **wp_** puede ser susceptible a vulnerabilidades. 2- No uses el **functions.php**, usa CodeSnippets como mucho. Yo que tu me creaba mi propio plugin para hacer todos los snippets que quiera.

Comment: Justo iba a comentar algo similar. Yo uso mi propio plugin para todo lo personalizado que tengo que hacer. CodeSnippets ya lo deje hace tiempos...

Comment: Tengo un plugin perosnalizado, pasaré el código que tengo en functions.php ahí. Y gracias por el consejo! le quitaré el prefijo wp_. ¿Pero alguien tiene idea por qué no me deja editar otros usuarios? ¿O por qué aparece el error "ID de usuario no válido"?